# why does my set still have repetitive values?

Tags: python, dataframe, hash, data-cleaning

So I used a class function to create a data frame to do some data cleaning, and here is my code:

```
class Item():
    __name = ""
    __cost = 0
    __gender = ""
    __prime = ""

    def has_all_properties(self):
        return bool(self.__name and not math.isnan(self.__cost) and self.__gender and self.__prime)
    def clean(self):
        return bool(self.__name and self.__cost <=20 and self.__gender == "male" and self.__prime == "yes")
    
    def __init__(self, name, cost, gender, prime):
        self.__name = name
        self.__cost = cost
        self.__gender = gender
        self.__prime = prime
    def __eq__(self, other):
        self.__name == other.__name
        self.__cost == other.__cost
        self.__gender == other.__gender
        self.__prime == other.__prime
   
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.__name, self.__cost, self.__gender, self.__prime))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Item({self.__name},{self.__cost},{self.__gender},{self.__prime})"

    def __tuple__(self): 
        return self.__name, self.__cost, self.__gender, self.__prime

mylist = {Item(*k) for k in array}
print(mylist)
filtered = filter(Item.has_all_properties, mylist)
clean = filter(Item.clean, filtered)
result = list(clean)
#print(result)
```

the array looks something like this:

```
array = [['comic', 20.0, 'male', 'yes'], ['paint', 14.0, 'male', 'no'], ['pen', 5.0, 'female', 'yes'], ['phone case', 9.0, 'female', 'no'], ['headphone', 40.0, 'male', 'yes'], [None, 17.0, 'male', 'yes'], ['pencil ', 40.0, 'female', 'yes'], ['coat', nan, 'male', 'yes'], ['underwear', 15.0, 'male', 'yes'], ['shorts', 17.0, 'female', 'no'], ['goggles', 25.0, 'male', 'no'], ['comic', 20.0, 'male', 'yes'], ['watch', 55.0, 'male', 'yes'], ['notebook', 10.0, 'female', 'no'], ['mug', 58.0, 'male', 'no'], ['UNO', 15.0, None, None]... and so on]
```

so, in the array, there are repeating elements such as `['comic', 20.0, 'male', 'yes']` so I wish to use a set to remove the extra ones and keep only one. However, when I use the `set` and added a `__eq__ and __hash__` the result `mylist` is still having repeating values.

HOw should I fix the python code, thank you in advance.

Comment: Your `__eq__` method doesn't return anything.

Comment: Why are you using all the name mangling?

Comment: Your `__eq__` method *always returns `None`*.

Comment: as an aside, stop using double-underscore name-mangling like that. You should use a *single* underscore if you want to signal that some attribute is not part of the public API

Comment: Also, `__tuple__` is not a special method... And don't create a bunch of pointless class attributes that are only going to be shadowed in the `__init__`.

Comment: You should probably just use a namedtuple type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__eq__` method needs to return the result of all the comparisons.

```
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__name == other.__name and \
            self.__cost == other.__cost and \
            self.__gender == other.__gender and \
            self.__prime == other.__prime
```

Answer (score 1):

Verify that `other` is `Item` as well

```
class Item:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Item):
            return self.__name == other.__name and \
                   self.__cost == other.__cost and \
                   self.__gender == other.__gender and \
                   self.__prime == other.__prime

        return NotImplemented
```

Comment: Technically, this should really return `NotImplemented` instead of `False`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga OK. Code was modified.